# Check total memory of Redis v2.8

Tags: memory, redis

I'm using [Redis Desktop Manager](https://redisdesktop.com/download) For Windows to connect and run commands.
[INFO](http://redis.io/commands/INFO) command returns information and statistics about the Redis server.
A part of return string for the `INFO` command is as below (taken from [here](http://redis.io/commands/INFO)):

```
.
.
.    
# Memory
used_memory:9338208
used_memory_human:8.91M
used_memory_rss:14454784
used_memory_rss_human:13.79M
used_memory_peak:13677584
used_memory_peak_human:13.04M
total_system_memory:4142215168
total_system_memory_human:3.86G
.
.
.
```

But in my case I'm not getting `total_system_memory` and `total_system_memory_human` values.
It's just missing when I run `INFO` command.
Actual output when I run `INFO`:

```
.
.
.
# Memory
used_memory:561892576
used_memory_human:535.86M
used_memory_rss:575049728
used_memory_peak:562210816
used_memory_peak_human:536.17M
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.02
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

# Persistence
loading:0
.
.
.
```

So, How can I know the total memory of my Redis instance?

Answer (score 1):

It's about the version change.

- First one you are referring is a higher version probably 3.2 (guess)
- Your server is a previous one.

You can check the version in INFO command.  redis_version it is.

Edit :
Think of it as a feature. In the previous version there is no such thing called total system memory. In the higher versions they have provided that feature.  That's all.

Basically in v2.8 the total system memory is the ram of your system unless until you have changed the redis.conf file with the maxmemory value.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question! should be a comment.

Comment: Well I dont have access to that system. Only things I have is the connection string and a terminal to execute redis commands. Now how will i know the total memory

Comment: Ask whenever operates the machine.

Comment: I don't think you can see the total memory if you don't have access to the machine. It's a limitation in v2.8

Comment: In elasticache redis we see the same issue except that the variable is called `maxmemory`.  It isn't available for redis 2.8 and you have to guess a value based on the instance size.